# i keep getting a "missing right parenthesis" error. But cannot see anything visibly wrong

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and I have been trying to make this table however when I put the duration of the tour as an integer that would last an hour and a half. however, it keeps showing up as red and giving the error message that it's "missing the right parentheses". I've only been taught how to use integers but not sure if this is the right one to use in this situation.

and for the table that will be referenced from that table is saying that there is nothing to reference and rightfully so because I have yet to make the table. but if anybody could help with this problem it would be much appreciated!

```sql
create table qualification
( tour_id         varchar2(8)   not null
, guide           varchar2(8)   null
, date_passed     date          null
, primary key (tour_id, guide)
, foreign key (guide) references guide(guide_no)
, foreign key (tour_id) references tour(tour_id) 
);

create table tour
( tour_id      varchar2(8)         primary key
, tour_name    varchar2(20)        not null
, duration_of_tour  integer (180)  null
, standard_cost     integer (6,2)  not null
);
```

Comment: just add slashes after each statement terminating semicolons.

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan I have added the slashes and I am still getting the same error message with a highlight between the integer and (180)

Comment: remove `(180)` too(a column with integer data type cannot have a defined length). Btw, get rid of those `null`s, which are redundant, too.

Comment: integer datatype should not have any length defined, remove (180) and (6,2). But if the data can contain fractions (e.g. cents) then integer is wrong data type, use something like number(10,2)
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle has the NUMBER datatype.

INTEGER(n,m) wouldn't work anywhere.
Standard SQL would be DECIMAL(n,m) then.

So this statement will work

```
create table tour
( tour_id      varchar2(8)         primary key
, tour_name    varchar2(20)        not null
, duration_of_tour  number(38,0)  null
, standard_cost     number(6,2)  not null
);
```

But the size of duration_of_tour might be too big.

Answer (score 2):

At the best of my knowledge, you can't define a column with a type of integer WITH precision. The "int" or "integer" are just aliases for type number with already defined precision. I'm almost sure it is aliases for max allowed - "number(38)"

So, it's either "integer" or "number(x,y)"

However if you updated your col type from integer(180) to number(180) you'll hit another error because number can't be 180 digits long.

Check [this doc](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021), perhaps you'll find something useful there